# Android studio installing error : com.codota.intellij.common.core.CodotaMain does not define or inherit

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After installing latest android studio, when started below error is given

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You ll have to delete that plugin by finding the Android studio installation directory.

This link will help you to find the installation directory of Android studio.

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/153q8le/comment/jsppki6/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button

find the codota folder under the plugins .Then Delete it .Then restart the android studio.

This worked for me.